# How to update the markers in real-time using ajax

Tags: javascript, leaflet

May I know how do I update the location in real-time, if the location value has been changed. The current code is what I used to retrieve the data from the database. I tried many solutions such as set interval or timeout but that did not help me in solving the problem.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: ')',

    success: function (data, status, xhr) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Table.length; i++) {

            if (createdA === false) {

                for (var a = 0; a <= 200; a++) {

                    a1 = data.Table[i].Latitude;
                    a2 = data.Table[i].Longitude;
                    a5 = data.Table[i].DeviceImei;
                }
                createMarkerA([a1, a2]);
                shownA = true;
                createdA = true;
                setInterval(groupOne(), 10000);
            }
            else if (shownA === false) {
                for (var a3 = 0; a3 < 200; a3++) {
                    showMarker(markersA[a3]);
                    shownA = true;
                }

            }
            else if (shownA === true) {
                for (var a4 = 0; a4 < 200; a4++) {
                    hideMarker(markersA[a4]);
                    shownA = false;
                }

            }

        }

    },

    error: function (xhr) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);

    }

});
```

//This is the code to initialize the map

```
 //centers the map at using the 2 points as reference
    var center = L.bounds([, ], [, ]).getCenter();

    //it sets the map to the pre-defined div container
    var map = L.map('test_map').setView([center.x, center.y], 12);

    var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://maps-{s}.onemap.sg/v3/Original/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        detectRetina: true,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 11
    });
    basemap.addTo(map);

    var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements

    map.addLayer(markersLayer);
    var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
        position: 'topright',
        layer: markersLayer,
        initial: false,
        zoom: 18,
        marker: false
    })
    map.addControl(controlSearch);



    L.circle([, ], 50, { color: '#DA2E2E', opacity: 2, fillColor: 'blue', fillOpacity: .3 }).bindPopup('').addTo(map);
    L.circle([, ], 50, { color: '#DA2E2E', opacity: 2, fillColor: 'blue', fillOpacity: .3 }).bindPopup('').addTo(map);
```

// The code to initialize the markers

```
var markers = [];

function pushMarker(marker) {
 markers.push(marker);
 }

function createMarker(data) {
 var marker = new L.marker([data[0], data[1]]);
 pushMarker(marker);
 showMarker(marker);
 }

 //General Functions
 function hideMarker(marker) {
 map.removeLayer(marker);
  }

 function showMarker(marker) {
 map.addLayer(marker);
   }

   var createdA = false;
   var shownA = false;
   var markersA = [];

   var a1;
   var a2;
   var a5;



     function createMarkerA(data) {

      $.ajax({

    type: "GET",

    url: '',


    success: function (data, status, xhr) {


        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {





            var customPopup = 'Coordinates X: ' + data.Table[i].Latitude + '</br>Coordinates Z: ' + data.Table[i].Longitude + '</br>Station: ' + data.Table[i].Station + ' </br> Box: ' + data.Table[i].Box + '</br > Timestamp: ' + data.Table[i].LocationSend;
            var customOptions =
            {
                'maxWidth': '500',
                'className': 'custom'
            };
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data.Table[i].Latitude, data.Table[i].Longitude, data.Table[i].Station));
            marker.bindPopup(customPopup, customOptions);
            pushMarker(marker);
            showMarker(marker);


        }

    },


    error: function (xhr) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);

    }



});

  }
  function groupOne() {

$.ajax({


    type: "GET",
    url: '',


    success: function (data, status, xhr) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            if (createdA === false) {

                for (var a = 0; a < 200; a++) {

                    a1 = data.Table[i].Latitude;
                    a2 = data.Table[i].Longitude;
                }
                createMarkerA([a1, a2]);
                shownA = true;
                createdA = true;

            }
            else if (shownA === false) {
                for (var a3 = 0; a3 <= 4; a3++) {
                    showMarker(markersA[a3]);
                    shownA = true;
                }

            }
            else if (shownA === true) {
                for (var a4 = 0; a4 <= 4; a4++) {
                    hideMarker(markersA[a4]);
                    shownA = false;
                }

            }





        }


    },




    error: function (xhr) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);

    }




});
```

Comment: The setInteval do not take inside the ajax call .

Comment: This ajax call is difine in a function and the function is called inside time interval

Comment: hmm but how am i able to update the markers every 5 sec after the ajax has completed the call ?

Comment: according your call it will automatic chnaged after re intialized the map

Comment: i tried but it does not change unless i have to refresh the web page

Comment: no necessery to refresh the page .only refresh the map.can display how to intialized the map with marker

Comment: can display how to define the function and call with ajax in time interval

Comment: @LDS I have added the code for the map as well as the markers.

Comment: map.removeLayer(marker)  -> this is not working for me. So this may not work for you. Insted of this function use that I

am used like  markers[i].setLatLng(location); If you get the data from data base for updating the location that you develop must have to refresh.

But if you call the ajax from time interval need not to refresh.Ok I am try to solve in your code in my system .Please wait

Answer (score 0):

Just I am taking some static points to change the point without refresh the page

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet geolocate example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var center = L.bounds([40.712, -74.227], [40.774, -74.125]).getCenter();
        //alert(center.x);
        function init() {
            
            map = new L.Map('map');
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);
            map.attributionControl.setPrefix(''); // Don't show the 'Powered by Leaflet' text.
            var seconds = 0.005;
            map.setView(new L.LatLng(center.x, center.y), 12);
            setmarkers(seconds);
            var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
                center.x = center.x + seconds + 0.01;
                center.y = center.y + seconds + 0.01;
                
                getmarkers(seconds);
                seconds = seconds + 0.01;
                
            }, 2000);

            
            
        }
        function getmarkers(v) {
            //alert(v);
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var location = new L.LatLng(center.x + i * v, center.y + i * v);
                markers[i].setLatLng(location);
                markers[i].addTo(map);
            }
        }
        function setmarkers(v) {
            
            alert(v);
            var radius = 30;
            
        

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var location = new L.LatLng(center.x + i * v, center.y + i * v)
                var mark = L.marker(location);
                markers.push(mark);
               
            }

          
        }
        function onLocationFound(e) {
            var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
            radius = 30;
            var location = e.latlng
            L.marker(location).addTo(map)
            L.circle(location, radius).addTo(map);
            alert(location.lat);
            alert(location.lng);
            addinlocations(location);
        }

        function onLocationError(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

        function getLocationLeaflet() {
            map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
            map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

            map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16 });
        }
        function pushMarker(marker) {
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        function addinlocations(pot) {

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var nmarker = new L.LatLng(pot.lat + i * 0.5, pot.lng * 0.5);
                var radius = 20;

                var location = nmarker
                L.marker(location).addTo(map)
                L.circle(location, radius).addTo(map);
               // pushMarker(nmarker);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:init();">
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Locate me!" onClick="javascript:getLocationLeaflet();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not work for me i would want it such that if the lat and long changes the marker location will be updated

Comment: map.removeLayer(marker)  -> this is not working for me. So this may not work for you. Insted of this function use that I

am used like  markers[i].setLatLng(location); If you get the data from data base for updating the location that you develop must have to refresh.

But if you call the ajax from time interval need not to refresh.Ok I am try to solve in your code in my system .Please wait

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet geolocate example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var createdA = false;
        var shownA = false;
        var markersA = [];
        var markersA = [];
        var a1;
        var a2;
        var a5;
        
        var center = L.bounds([39.61, -105.02], [39.77, -105.23]).getCenter();
        
        function init() {
            
            map = new L.Map('test_map').setView(new L.LatLng(center.x, center.y), 12);;
            var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
                detectRetina: true,
                maxZoom: 20,
                minZoom: 9
            });
            basemap.addTo(map);
            
           
            var data = [];
            var d1 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.61, Longitude: -105.02, Station: 'This is Littleton, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing1' } };
            var d2 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.74, Longitude: -104.99, Station: 'This is Denver, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing2' } };
            var d3 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.73, Longitude: -104.8, Station: 'This is Aurora, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing3' } };
            var d4 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.733, Longitude: -104.821, Station: 'This is Littleton, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing4' } };
            var d5 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.742, Longitude: -105.002, Station: 'This is Denver, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing5' } };
            var d6 = { Table: { Latitude: 39.734, Longitude: -104.811, Station: 'This is Aurora, CO.', Box: 'Box', LocationSend: 'testing6' } };
            data.push(d1);
            data.push(d2);
            data.push(d3);
            data.push(d4);
            data.push(d5);
            data.push(d6);

            markersA.push(L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.61, -105.02)));
            markersA.push(L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.74, -104.99)));
            markersA.push(L.marker(new L.LatLng(39.73, -104.8)));
            map.addLayer(markersA[0]);
            map.addLayer(markersA[1]);
            map.addLayer(markersA[2]);
          
           
            var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
               
                groupOne(data);
                
            }, 2000);
            var markersLayer = L.layerGroup(markersA);

            map.addLayer(markersLayer);
            var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
                position: 'topright',
                layer: markersLayer,
                initial: false,
                zoom: 15,
                marker: false
            })
            map.addControl(controlSearch);
           
        }
        function pushMarker(marker) {
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        function createMarker(data) {
            var marker = new L.marker([data[0], data[1]]);
            pushMarker(marker);
           
        }
        function showMarker(marker) {
           
            map.addLayer(marker);
        }
        function hideMarker(marker, i) {
           
            var locate = marker.getLatLng();
           
            markersA[i].setLatLng(locate);
          
           
        }
        function createMarkerA(data) {
            var valid = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                
                var customPopup = 'Coordinates X: ' + data[i].Table.Latitude + '</br>Coordinates Z: ' + data[i].Table.Longitude + '</br>Station: ' + data[i].Table.Station + ' </br> Box: ' + data[i].Table.Box + '</br > Timestamp: ' + data[i].Table.LocationSend;
               
                //var customOptions =
                //            {
                //                'maxWidth': '500',
                //                'className': 'custom'
                //            };
                        //var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data[i].Table.Latitude, data[i].Table.Longitude, data[i].Table.Station));
                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data[i].Table.Latitude, data[i].Table.Longitude));
                        marker.bindPopup(customPopup);
                pushMarker(marker);
            

              }
             
        }
        

        function groupOne(data) {
            
            //$.ajax({
            //    type: "GET",
            //    url: '',
            //    data:data,
            //    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                   
                    

                        if (createdA == false) {
                            createMarkerA(data);
                          
                            shownA = true;
                            createdA = true;
                           
                        }
                        else if (shownA == false) {
                           
                            for (var a = 0; a <= 2; a++) {
                                hideMarker(markers[a],a);
                                
                            }
                            shownA = true;

                        }
                        else if (shownA == true) {
                           
                            for (var aa = 3;aa<=5;aa++) {
                                var i = aa - 3;
                                hideMarker(markers[aa], i);
                                                             
                            }
                            shownA = false;
                           
                        }

                    


            //}
            //,
                //error: function (xhr) {

                //    alert(xhr.responseText);

                //}
            //});

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:init();">
    <div id="test_map" style="height: 500px"></div>
   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works but when i change the url of the map suddenly the map is not showing

Comment: It may happen due to versionity.By the way what is the url you changed

Comment: Sorry to bother you again i tried to send a dummy location to the database but the map still show the same location as before

Comment: how to retrive dummy data from the data base

Comment: i use ajax to retrieve the data from the database

Comment: first check the url and verify whether the data is comming or not

Comment: i am sure that the data is updated when i send the dummy location to the database as the url that i have only get the latest location from the database. I also tried with an app such as postman

Comment: I just commeted your ajax call .Please display the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Leaflet geolocate example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<script language="javascript">
    var markers = [];
    var createdA = false;
    var shownA = false;
    var markersA = [];
    var markersA = [];
    var a1;
    var a2;
    var a5;
    var data1 = [];
    var center = L.bounds([1.56073, 104.11475], [1.16, 103.502]).getCenter();

    function init() {

        map = new L.Map('test_map').setView(new L.LatLng(center.x, center.y), 12);;
        var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://maps- 
      {s}.onemap.sg/v3/Original/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '<img src="https://docs.onemap.sg/maps/images/oneMap64- 
     01.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;"/> New OneMap | Map data © contributors, 
     <a href="http://SLA.gov.sg">Singapore Land Authority</a>',
            detectRetina: true,
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 9
        });
        basemap.addTo(map);

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            url: '',


            success: function (data, status, xhr) {


                for (var i = 0; i < data.Table.length; i++) {
                    for (var s = 1; s < data.Table.length; s++) {
                        var d1 = { Table: { Latitude: data.Table[i].Latitude, 
     Longitude: data.Table[i].Longitude, Station: 'This is Littleton, CO.', Box: 
     'Box', LocationSend: 'testing1' } };
                        var d2 = { Table: { Latitude: data.Table[s].Latitude, 
     Longitude: data.Table[s].Longitude, Station: 'This is Denver, CO.', Box: 'Box', 
     LocationSend: 'testing2' } };
                        data1.push(d1);
                        data1.push(d2);


                        markersA.push(L.marker(new L.LatLng(data.Table[i].Latitude, 
    data.Table[i].Longitude)));
                        markersA.push(L.marker(new L.LatLng(data.Table[s].Latitude, 
    data.Table[s].Longitude)));
                        map.addLayer(markersA[0]);
                        map.addLayer(markersA[1]);
                    }




                }


            },


            error: function (xhr) {

                alert(xhr.responseText);

            }

        });

        var myTimer = setInterval(function () {


            groupOne(data1);

        }, 2000);

    }
    function pushMarker(marker) {
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    function createMarker(data1) {
        var marker = new L.marker([data1[0], data1[1]]);
        pushMarker(marker);

    }
    function showMarker(marker) {

        map.addLayer(marker);
    }
    function hideMarker(marker, i) {

        var locate = marker.getLatLng();

        markersA[i].setLatLng(locate);


    }
    function createMarkerA(data1) {
        var valid = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {

            var customPopup = 'Coordinates X: ' + data1[i].Table.Latitude + 
     '</br>Coordinates Z: ' + data1[i].Table.Longitude + '</br>Station: ' + 
     data1[i].Table.Station + ' </br> Box: ' + data1[i].Table.Box + '</br > 
     Timestamp: ' + data1[i].Table.LocationSend;

            //var customOptions =
            //            {
            //                'maxWidth': '500',
            //                'className': 'custom'
            //            };
            //var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data[i].Table.Latitude, 
      data[i].Table.Longitude, data[i].Table.Station));
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data1[i].Table.Latitude, 
      data1[i].Table.Longitude));
            marker.bindPopup(customPopup);
            pushMarker(marker);


        }

    }


    function groupOne(data) {

        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "GET",
        //    url: '',
        //    data:data,
        //    success: function (data, status, xhr) {



        if (createdA == false) {
            createMarkerA(data);

            shownA = true;
            createdA = true;

        }
        else if (shownA == false) {

            for (var a = 0; a <= 2; a++) {
                hideMarker(markers[a], a);

            }
            shownA = true;

        }
        else if (shownA == true) {

            for (var aa = 3; aa <= 5; aa++) {
                var i = aa - 3;
                hideMarker(markers[aa], i);

            }
            shownA = false;

        }




        //}
        //,
        //error: function (xhr) {

        //    alert(xhr.responseText);

        //}
        //});

    }
</script>

 </head>
 <body onLoad="javascript:init();">
<div id='test_map' style=" height: 800px; "></div>
```